# Show rows from table which another table doesn't contain

Tags: sql, mariadb

Basically, I want to show all data from a certain table, which another table doesn't contain with a certain condition.

I want to show all the people who haven't filled in their availability. This is what I do to see who have filled in their availability in SQL:

```
SELECT availability_id, availability_date, availability_start, availability_end, info_id, info_firstname, info_surname, job_name
FROM Availability
FULL JOIN Info
ON Availability.availability_info_id = Info.info_id
LEFT JOIN Job
ON Job.job_id = Info.info_job_id
WHERE Availability.availability_date = '2019-9-20'; //today
```

So this shows the people who are available today.

Now I want to show the people who haven't filled in their availability. So I want to show everyone in table '**Info**', who are not in table '**Availability**' where **date = 2019-09-20**.

How do I do this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.   Also, qualify your column references so you *and other people* know where the columns come from.  What does it mean to "fill in availability"?  Where is the "person" in this data?

Comment: There is no FULL JOIN in either MariaDB or MySQL. What RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: Hint: Move the condition for date to `LEFT JOIN.. ON` and then use `IS NULL` on the right-side table of `LEFT JOIN` to filter.

Comment: Madhur, FULL JOIN seems to do the job of FULL OUTER JOIN. I know what you mean. But I get an error everytime I try FULL OUTER JOIN. So I got along with FULL JOIN. I'm testing on 000webhost.com

Comment: @user2598506 Which RDBMS product you are using ? SQL Server ? MariaDB/MySQL ? Oracle ? By the way, MariaDB/MySQL dont support FULL JOIN or FULL OUTER JOIN yet...

Comment: It says the server is MariaDB. Anyways, I don't know how or why, but FULL JOIN does the job. I get the expected data result for **availability**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should do it. 
It lists everything from Info where there's no record in Availability for a certain date.

```
SELECT  I.* 
FROM    Info I
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM    Availability A
    WHERE   A.availability_info_id = I.info_id
        AND A.availability_date = '2019-9-20' -- today
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked and this is exactly what I needed

Comment: What does 'SELECT 1' mean btw?

Comment: @user2598506 - it's just `select constant`

Answer (score 1):

```
--use derived table  and case statment:

--you can give your date in case statement and give proper aliases in order to avoid errors during execution

--this query will give you all records from info table and you can also get info for availability and not available also


SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT Availability.availability_id, Availability.availability_date, Availability.availability_start, Availability.availability_end, Info.info_id, Info.info_firstname, Info.info_surname, Job.job_name
        ,case when  Availability.availability_date = '2019-09-20' then 'AVAILABLE'
              ELSE 'NOT AVAILABLE'
              END STATUS
FROM        Info
left join   Availability
ON          Availability.availability_info_id = Info.info_id
LEFT JOIN   Job
ON          Job.job_id = Info.info_job_id
WHERE Availability.availability_date = '2019-09-20'; --//today
) T
WHERE STATUS='NOT AVAILABLE' --THIS WILL GIVE YOU INFO WHICH HAS NO '2019-09-20' IN availability_date COLUMN
```